# Order skills in numeric order(category)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have to sort things by asc order but one of the columns as numeric value which is okay.

`Table jobs`

```
skill                     skill_number_group

20 system analysis                10
API  design                       10
process modelling                 10
10 event management              8
guest list                        8
.NET                               7
entertainment                     8
15 programming                    7
php                               7
java                              7
pl/sql and sql                    7
DEM                               10
hosting                           8
```

I hope you get the idea.

Basically anything with a numeric value at the beginning is a category  e.g.   10 event management

I have a done

`select * from jobs order by skill_number_group, skills`

but the issue with this is that it means the numbers of basically the result is how it is on the database.

What I am aiming to do is to have the result in order so its like this

```
skill                     skill_number_group

10 event management              8
guest list                        8
hosting                           8
entertainment                     8
15 programming                    7
php                               7
java                              7
pl/sql and sql                    7
.NET                              7
20 system analysis                10
API  design                       10
DEM                               10
process modelling                 10
```

Basically the `skills` is in a number order follow by skills in the group

Comment: Bad data model.  You should have a column to distinguish categories from skills, or preferable a table of categories linked to the table of skills.  With this you are into tricky analytic function queries.

Comment: @TonyAndrews i didnt design it, i wasn't in the planning team

Comment: @user3057514 - Well, whoever made the decision on the planning team does **not** have the proper skillset to make that decision.  Not only are they violating [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), it's going to fail miserably if a skill has a number as part of its name.  And problems with foreign languages.  I'm also really concerned about the fact that the numbers appear to be 5 apart, and that the value is being used for ordering (keys should only be used for the relations - the value and/or ordering should be considered meaningless).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to add a column with said numeric and `order by` both columns?

The best idea here is to basicly reconsider data structure.

Comment: it will not work as it will end up still having to order it with `skills` column which mean that first few results will be anything with a numeric value that the beginning e.g. `10 event management`, `15 programming `, `20 system analysis`. That's basically what the first 3 results will be.